# Make Call to Back-end, Multiple Path Variables, Ext Js

Tags: java, javascript, hibernate, extjs

I've got a RESTful call that I'd like to make to the back end of my application. The front end is written in Ext JS (JavaScript) the back-end in JAVA utilizing Hibernate. The application utilizes the MVC design pattern.

On the back end, I've got a GET request endpoint with a "mapping" akin to: `thing/{thingOne}/otherThing/{thingTwo}`.

Ext JS provides a number of functions on their stores for hitting a back end through a model's proxy: `.load()`, `.save()`, `.remove()`. Each of these is able to take multiple arguments for their `[options]` parameter; however, I am attempting to find documentation that shows me how to make a multi-parametered request to a back-end GET endpoint and have found none, so far.

My assumption is that the call would be structured like: `.load("param1", "param2")` based upon the documentation for `.save()` and `.remove()`. Here's the doc. for [save](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save), for [remove](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store), and [load](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load).

So, how do I make a GET call to the back end with multiple parameters? Am I even in the correct ballpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "extraparams" on proxy.

[sencha api 4.2.2 - extraparams on store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Direct-cfg-extraParams)

```
    var formOperation = [];
    var example = {"city":"Manchester"};
    Ext.Object.merge(formOperacion,example);
    store.getProxy().extraParams = formOperation;
    store.load();
```

Another solution:

[Sencha api - store - Dynamic Loading](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

```
store.load({
    params: {
        group: 3,
        type: 'user'
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // do something after the load finishes
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Comment: I will read more about this. In your first example, what had you intended to do with `var example`?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add 'example' var to 'arrayOperation'.

Answer (score 0):

Build the request's URL as a concatenated string, including the arguments:

```
var requestUrl = 'thingOne/' + thingOneVar + '/otherThing/' + otherThingVar;
```

Note that whether your "built" `string` should be prefixed with a `/` depends upon how your model's proxy is configured. Essentially, you are aiming for a legitimate request url.

And make a request via the proxy (here, I'm using AJAX):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : requestUrl,
    // ....
});
```

The then needs to be handled by a callback or as a promise.